# alert is not working?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
function validate_form()
{
    var pin=document.contactform.Pin;
    if(pin.value.length !=6)
    {
        alert("Length of pin code must be six character");
        pin.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
         alert('Else part ');
    }
}
```

the alert function within if statement is not working

Comment: alert won't be not working, are you sure your code enter the if statement?

Comment: Are you sure that the code in the `if` statement gets called?

Comment: the alert code is fine. try to debug the IF statement

Comment: first check your function is calling or not, put aler in first line of function

Comment: @MayankSharma <tr>
    <td style="width:130px;"><label for="pin">Pin:</label></td>
    <td style="width:212px;align:left;"><input type="text" maxlength="6" name="Pin"></td>
   </tr>. validate_form() is called onSubmit

Comment: please update your code in the question

Answer (score 0):

your

```
var pin=document.contactform.Pin;
```

variable is not creating syntax error , check what are you passing in to the variable , otherwise it works fine